# Which is the intersection?

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I am looking at the last question of the following exercise:

[image]

---

$$$$

Which exactly is the intersection of any surface from one family of the triply orthogonal system with any surface from another family?

Comment: **Hint** Any surface in the system (say, in the first family) is a set $\{(u_0, v, w)\} \subset W$, where $u_0$ is fixed.

Comment: Is the intersection of the surfaces $\{(u_0,v,w)\}$, $\{(u,v_0,w)\}$, $\{(u,v,w_0)\}$, for example the curve $u_0$ ? @Travis

Comment: Where those three surfaces intersect, we must have $u = u_0, v = v_0, w = w_0$, and so defines just a particular point $(u_0, v_0, w_0)$ (at least, provided that point is in $W$, otherwise the intersection in empty). The intersection of the first two, for example, is the set of all points of the form $(u_0, v_0, w)$ in $W$, which is an (again, possibly empty) curve parameterized by $w$.

Comment: It might be useful to keep in mind the prototypical example of such a system, for which $\Sigma$ is just the identity map. Then, the surfaces in the system are really just planes (or more precisely, intersections of planes with $W$), and the intersections of two such surfaces is just a line (again, really the intersection of a line with $W$).

Comment: We want a line not a point of intersection, or not? @Travis

Comment: Yes: The intersection of a surface from one family and a surface from another is generically a curve, and the intersection of three surfaces, one from each family is generically a point.

Comment: Ah ok!! To show that the intersection is a line of curvature on both surfaces, do we use the second question, as user26977 proposed in the answer? If so, having that the matrix of the Weingarten map is diagonal, we have that the principal curvatures are the eigenvalues of this matrix, which are the elements of the diagonal of the Weingarten map and then the eigenvectors are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. 
Does this imply that the tangent vector of the curve is a principal vector of the surface? How? @Travis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of two surfaces is a curve $\Sigma(u_0,v_0,w)$ resp. ($\Sigma(u_0,v,w_0)$, $\Sigma(u,v_0,w_0)$) which has two of three parameters fixed. These curves are coordinate lines on a surfaces patches defined by $\Sigma$.

From the second part of the exercise you know that matrices of both first and second fundamental form are diagonal and therefore lines of curvature are coordinate lines.

Comment: How do we conclude that the coordinate lines are lines of curvature when we know that matrices of both first and second fundamental form are diagonal?

Comment: Weingarten map has a diagonal matrix as well. The principal curvatures are it's eigenvalues (which are the values on the diagonal of Weingarten map). Then compute the eigenvectors  and you will get $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$, i..e tangent vectors of coordinate lines..

Answer (score 2):

Let's call the three families the constant-$u$ family ($C_u$), the constant-$v$ family ($C_v$), and the constant-$w$ family ($C_w$).

A surface in the family $C_u$ is of the form
$$
G(v,w) = \Sigma(u_0,v,w)
$$
for some fixed $u=u_0$. Similarly, a surface in the family $C_v$ is of the form
$$
H(u,w) = \Sigma(u,v_0,w)
$$
for some fixed $v=v_0$. The intersection of the surfaces $G$ and $H$ is the curve
$$
F(w) = \Sigma(u_0, v_0, w)
$$
This answers the question you asked, but doesn't tell you how to do the homework problem.

Comment: To show that the intersection is a line of curvature on both surfaces, do we use the second question, as user26977 proposed in the answer? If so, having that the matrix of the Weingarten map is diagonal, we have that the principal curvatures are the eigenvalues of this matrix, which are the elements of the diagonal of the Weingarten map and then the eigenvectors are $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. 
Does this imply that the tangent vector of the curve is a principal vector of the surface? How?

Comment: I'm guessing here: I suppose expressions like $(1,0)$ denote coordinates with respect to the basis whose elements are partial derivative vectors. So, in general, $(a,b)$ means $a\mathbf{S}_u + b\mathbf{S}_v$. In particular, then $(1,0)$ means $\mathbf{S}_u$. But $\mathbf{S}_u$ is the tangent vector of the curve on which $v$ and $w$ are constant. And the curve where $v$ and $w$ are constant is one of the intersection curves.

Comment: I got it!! Thank you!! :-)